# GET request executes twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm currently testing around with my RPi Zero WH and a sound sensor connected to a GPIO PIN. Everytime a sound is detected the API sends a notification to my Alexa via HTTP Request. Only problem is that for some reason the request gets executed twice and my Alexa plays the sounds one above the other.

This is the Python3 Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import requests

# GPIO SETUP
channel = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)

def callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel):
        r = requests.get("https://api-v2.voicemonkey.io/trigger?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&device=doorbell-trigger")
        print(r.status_code)

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=300)  # Detect only rising edge
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)  # Assign function to GPIO PIN, run function on change

# Infinite loop
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

The API is definitely not the problem because when I repleace it with a simple print function everything works just as it should.

Comment: Perhaps your issue is a race condition? Could the same sound be triggering multiple events? I would investigate adding a locking mechanism in your callback function such that it will only send a GET request if a GET is not already in progress.

Comment: Have you tried increasing your bounce time? Say to 1000?

Comment: If you don't have the means to analyse the signal, e.g., an oscilloscope you should assume a noisy signal and mitigate in your handler or increase `bouncetime`. Is `if GPIO.input(channel):` in your call back function redundant? The [docs](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) also suggest adding a 0.1µF capacitor across the input.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem here is that the input from the sound sensor is detected twice for a single sound, it might work if you try adding a mechanism that only allows it to accept one input.
somethins like this:

```py
debounce_delay = 0.1
last_event_time = 0
```

and then in the callback function add something like

```py
if current_time - last_event_time >= debounce_delay:
        last_event_time = current_time
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).